# Redshift: 500310 Invalid Operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am using talend to insert data into a table on Amazon Redshift. The java code is producing by talend but `today()` function is not supported by Amazon Redshift.

I am trying to load a table from Salesforce and put it in Redshift using talend. When I am running the job from talend I have following error:

```
Exception in component tRedshiftOutput_1
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function today() does not exist;
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(ErrorResponse.java:1830)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(PGMessagingContext.java:804)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(PGMessagingContext.java:642)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(InboundMessagesPipeline.java:312)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(PGMessagingContext.java:1062)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.getErrorResponse(PGMessagingContext.java:1030)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.handleErrorsScenario3(PGClient.java:2481)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.handleErrors(PGClient.java:2346)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.directExecute(PGClient.java:1098)
    at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.directExecuteExtraMetadata(PGClient.java:1167)
[FATAL]: dw.create_invoice_0_1.create_invoice - tRedshiftOutput_1 [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function today() does not exist;
    at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGQueryExecutor.execute(PGQueryExecutor.java:210)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(Unknown Source)
    at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at dw.create_invoice_0_1.create_invoice.tSalesforceInput_1Process(create_invoice.java:4691)
    at dw.create_invoice_0_1.create_invoice.tSalesforceConnection_1Process(create_invoice.java:694)
    at dw.create_invoice_0_1.create_invoice.runJobInTOS(create_invoice.java:8761)
Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function today() does not exist
```

It seems that Amazon Redshift does not support `today()` function.

I  want to know how can I deal with that problem?

Comment: current_timestamp ?

Comment: I wonder whether you could [Create a User-Defined Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) called `today()` that returns `current_timestamp()`?

Comment: it coming from salesforce tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CURRENT_DATE function instead. You can find out more at the Redshift Date and Time functions documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/Date_functions_header.html